# SED command not replacing in actual file

Tags: bash, sed

I was migrating from Django 1.4 to 1.6 in which I have to replace all lines like 
`{% URL test arg1...%}` to `{% URL "test" arg1...}`

I used the following command:
`find ./ -type f -exec sed 's/{% url \([^" >][^ >]*\)/{% url "\1"/g' *.html '{}' \;`

It prints the desired output but do not make changes in the actual file? What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual of `sed`:

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

So you should add `-i` option to modify the files 'in place'.

Whole command:

`find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/{% url \([^" >][^ >]*\)/{% url "\1"/g' *.html '{}' \;`